# How to convert mysql query in magento collection

Tags: magento-1.9, database, query, join

this is my mysql query . I want to convert in magento collection.

reference link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253461/repeat-a-result-row-multiple-times-by-value-in-row

```
select Item , ItemName ,  Quantity
from yourtable A
cross join (select num from numbers) b
where a.Quantity <= b.num
```

I tried below code but not work

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToSelect(array('sku','qty_ordered'));

        $collection->getSelect()->joinCross(array('num' => 'new_table_qty_numbers'),array('main_table.sku','main_table.qty_ordered'))
        ->where('main_table.qty_ordered >= num.qty'); //also tried main_table.qty_ordered <= num.qty
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($collection->getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out!

```
$query = 'SELECT `item`,`itemname`,`qty` FROM `yourtableA` CROSS JOIN (SELECT `num` FROM `numbers`) `b` WHERE `a.qty` <= `b.num`';

$result = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')->fetchAll($query);
```

Let me know if this worked!